# Inserting elements in a range

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm reading C++ Primer (5th edition) and in 9.9.3 it mentions inserting in-range elements.

It is clearly stated in the book that it will cause a runtime error if the range of the copy is the same as the target container.

```cpp
// it'll cause a runtime error
vec.insert(vec.cbegin(), vec.cbegin(), vec.cend());
```

But it works in my computer, Why?

Comment: It is `UB` and it still works.

Comment: *But it works in my computer, Why?* -- Undefined behavior.

Comment: Just because code compiles doesn't make it correct.

Comment: Either the book is wrong or you misread it. C++ never guarantees a runtime error. Sometimes runtime errors are rather likely, but never guaranteed by the language. Could you give an exact quote?

Comment: It may work as long as the new `size()` isn't greater than the current `capacity()` otherwise it will invalidate iterators and wander off into the weeds.

Comment: My copy of this book may have been translated and UB turned out to be a running error.

Comment: "I find that a good working definition of "undefined behaviur" is "works for me, works for you, works during development and QA, but blows up in your most important customer's face"" --- Scott Meyers

Comment: Undefined just means the language specifies nothing in particular.  So anything a particular compiler does complies with the language standard.

Comment: @BreezyMain If "undefined behavior" was translated to "running error" (or "runtime error"), then the translator did not do a good job. There are plenty of instances of UB that likely will not cause a runtime error. Likely to give erroneous results, perhaps, but not a crash ("runtime error" suggests a crash of some sort).

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you for explaining it to me in such detail. I have one more question to ask. That the code like it: `list.insert(list.cbegin(), list.cbegin(), list.cend() - 1)` is also an `UB`? The iterator isn't same as target container.